# How to find all file or folder in the pc hd?

Tags: c#

"Sharp Project" (is the folder name which contain my project). It may copied to anywhere but I need to find it from pc HD untill string path matches "Sharp Project" then it does something to the .exe of my project inside the folder "Sharp Project". Just to protect users transfer or copy this project to use as their own project because this illegal for me.

Or

if my project is run the string path finds for the solution folder and remove exe file to prevent illegal user.

I am using C# language winform.

I need to know how to do it? How to find the solution folder? How to  remove the exe file and how to auto search for the solution folder?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Stack overflow is not a platform for writing code for you. Do some research on File handling and working with directories in C#, then ask another question if you have a specific problem with code examples.

Comment: `if my project is run the string path finds for the solution folder and remove exe file to prevent illegal user.` What if the folder is in a location that your program has `read` access to, but not `delete` rights? Why do you care if they copied the folder somewhere else?

Comment: There are numerous examples for searching for files, please update your question with a specific of a 1 issue with your code which is the [usual minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Dear mjwills, I am care for this issue because they not want to learn to create their own project but they copy and recolor and sell for other person. this is the resean I need to protect my copyright project. My project is create for graduate project but create in advance and it is used in business already but someone still try to sell in negative as their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search in all directories recursively:

```
public string searchDir(string parentDir)
{
    string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(parentDir, "*");
    foreach(var dir in dirs){
        if (dir.EndsWith("Sharp Project"))
            return dir;
    }
    foreach(var dir in dirs){
        return searchDir(dir);
    }
}
```

this will return the first folder that ends in "Sharp Project". You can adapt to find **all** "Sharp Project" directories.